# Prettify YAML with comments

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

### 1. Summary

I can't find, how I can automatically prettify my YAML files.

---

### 2. Data

Example:

I have `SashaPrettifyYAML.yaml` file:

```yaml
sasha_commands:
  # Sasha comment
  sasha_command_help: {call: sublime.command_help, caption: 'Sasha Command: Command Help'}
```

---

### 3. Expected behavior

I want to delete {braces}:

```yaml
sasha_commands:
  # Sasha comment
  sasha_command_help:
    call: sublime.command_help
    caption: 'Sasha Command: Command Help'
```

---

### 4. Not helped

1. [**Pretty YAML**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20YAML) (based on [**PyYAML**](http://pyyaml.org/)) and online formatters as [**YAML Formatter**](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter) and [**OnlineYAMLTools**](https://onlineyamltools.com/prettify-yaml) delete comments;
2. I can't find the required option in [**ruamel.yaml.cmd**](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml.cmd);
3. [**align-yaml**](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/align-yaml) align, not prettify YAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to do this in `ruamel.yaml.cmd`, but it is fairly straightforward to do this with a small python program and using `ruamel.yaml`, by loading and dumping in round-trip mode (the default).

The only thing you need to do is make sure the flow-style on the data-structure that is the value for the key `sasha_command_help` is set to block-style (which is how I interpret your definition of "prettifying YAML"):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
sasha_commands:
  # Sasha comment
  sasha_command_help: {call: sublime.command_help, caption: 'Sasha Command: Command Help'}
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['sasha_commands']['sasha_command_help'].fa.set_block_style()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this will exactly give the output you expect.

A recursive data structure walker can be found in `scalarstring.py` in the `ruamel.yaml` source, and adapted to make a generic "make-everything-block-style" routine:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def block_style(base):
    """
    This routine walks over a simple, i.e. consisting of dicts, lists and
    primitives, tree loaded from YAML. It recurses into dict values and list 
    items, and sets block-style on these.
    """
    if isinstance(base, dict):
        for k in base:
            try:
                base.fa.set_block_style()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            block_style(base[k])
    elif isinstance(base, list):
        for elem in base:
            try:
                base.fa.set_block_style()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            block_style(elem)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
file_in = sys.argv[1]
file_out = sys.argv[2]
with open(file_in) as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
block_style(data)
with open(file_out, 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(data, fp)
```

If you store the above in `prettifyyaml.py` you can call it with:

```
python prettifyyaml.py SashaPrettifyYAML.yaml Prettified.yaml
```

Since you are already using single quotes around the scalar that has embedded spaces, you won't see a change if you leave out     `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`. But if you had used a double quoted scalar then that line makes sure the double quotes are preserved.

Comment: Anthon, // **1.** Why you decline my edition? See [**`flake8 .` and `pydocstyle` output**](https://www.pastery.net/butuma/) of `prettifyyaml.py`. // **2.** Maybe you add this feature and sorting YAML to `ruamel.yaml.cmd`? I think, another users will be interested simply YAML prettify too. Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Import from the standard libraries should always come before non-standard libraries (followed by local imports), indiscriminate sorting. Most of the other stuff was unacceptable too, so I declined your edit. `flake` as such is nice but should not be applied indiscriminately within the restrictions of code posted on SO. If you find that problematic in answer to a question you post, let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Anthon, what do you think about include your code to `ruamel.yaml.cmd`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I wrote my own YAML beautifier https://github.com/wangkuiyi/yamlfmt.  I hope it helps.

I tried top results from Google, but none of them address the requirements of https://sqlflow.org/sqlflow, which I am leading:

- https://pypi.org/project/yamlfmt cannot handle a file of multiple YAML documents separated by ---
- https://github.com/devopyio/yamlfmt cannot handle multiple files.
- https://github.com/miekg/yamlfmt/blob/master/fmt.go cannot replace (inline edit) the input files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) tool - it's easy to install and use, and it's well maintained.
Supposing you have `example.yml` file to format, it can be processed by following ways:

- from file: `yq r --unwrapScalar -p pv -P example.yml '*'`
- from stdin: `cat example.yml | yq r --unwrapScalar -p pv -P - '*'`